# Jschema Validation not validating Array Objects when they are declared using $ref in the schema

Tags: .net, swagger, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, yamldotnet

JSON Schema validation is not validating Array items when items are declared using $ref in the Schema. It allows additional properties in the object which are not present in the schema although `additionalProperties` is set to False in the root schema object.
Here's a sample schema json schema where you can reproduce this issue.

```
{
  "StudentDetails": {
    "$ref": "#"
  },
  "Student":
  {
     "type": "object",
     "properties": {
        "name": {
            "description": "A link that can be used to fetch the next batch of results. The link contains an opaque continuation token.",
            "nullable": "true",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "The average rating of the title",
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
        }
     }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "unevaluatedItems": false,
  "unevaluatedProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Students": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/Student"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's an example object which should ideally fail the validation, but it actually succeeds.

```
       {
           ""Students"": [
                {
                     ""name"": ""X""
                },
                {
                     ""age"": 20
                },
                {
                     ""height"": 6
                }
           ]
         }
```

I expect that JSChema validation would fail saying "height" property is unevaluated.

I only see this issue with Arrays though. Any direct object validation works perfectly fine even with nested object structure.

Can someone please help me address this issue ?

I was testing out the JSchema validator for edge cases and ran into this issue where Array objects are not validated correctly.

Comment: What validator library do you use? What JSON Schema version do you use (e.g. 2020-12)? Can you post sample code showing how you do validation?

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
string fileName = @"tudendetailsschema.json";
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(text);

string jsonSchemaString = @" 
         {
           ""Students"": [
                {
                     ""age"": 20
                },
                {
                     ""height"": 6
                }
           ]
         }";                     
JObject schemaObject = JObject.Parse(jsonSchemaString);
bool isValid = schemaObject.IsValid(schema, out IList<string>  errorMessages);

Answer (score 0):

There is no version of the JSON Schema spec that both accepts `"nullable": true` (`null` was added as a possible `type`), and `"unevaluatedProperties": false`. What implementation are you using? Regardless, it is buggy as using a `$ref` inside an `items` is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm using the Newtonsoft Jschema to parse the string as Jschema and using Jobject's isValid method to validate.

Comment: I could only find one option to do this in C# which is Newtonsoft.jschema. Any other recommendation ?

Comment: https://json-schema.org/implementations.html